# Ruby on Rails: Creating a new children instance using the parent's id/Working with associated classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

One of my goal on this web app project is to make each tailor add or create products. So I made a **MCV** structure from scratch for the **Tailor** for the sign up page. And then I scaffold the **Product** since basic **CRUD** functions will be used by the **Tailor** to create a product. And then I put them into **has_many/belongs_to relationship**. I generated a migration which adds a column **tailor_id** into the **Product** class. Then I put these nested routes:

```
resources :tailors do
   resources :products
end 
resources :products #this is for debugging for whether a customer can see all the Products created by all the Tailors
```

then I ran **rake routes** and checked which path I can use to create a product with a given **tailor_id** then I decided to use the **/tailors/:tailor_id/products/new**. So I added a code which is a link in my tailor show page:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Product', new_tailor_product_path(@tailor.id) %>
```

and the I edited the **new** and **create** functions in the **products_controller** since the path is directed there) like this:

```
  def new
    @tailor = Tailor.find(params[:tailor_id])
    @product = @tailor.Product.new(params[@tailor])
  end

  def create
    @tailor = Tailor.find(params[:tailor_id])
    @product = @tailor.Product.new()
    @product.product_name = params[:product][:product_name]
    @product.product_description = params[:product][:product_description]
    @product.price = params[:product][:price]
    @product.tailor_id = params[:product][@tailor]
    @product.save
    redirect_to "/tailors/#{@tailor}"
  end
```

but the error says **Undefined method 'Product'** that occurs in the where the `@product = @tailor.Product.new(params[@tailor])`is

I don't really understand why is this an error because I'm pretty sure I called the class right (It's been taught to us that classes must begin with capital letter and is singular) and it's clear that I'm not calling a method.

Please explain the concept of calling the parent class and its data. Am I not allowed to call the **Tailor** class and its data inside the **product_controller** in this case? Is my approach wrong or am I in the right direction?

> Also, other Remarks and Error corrections about the other parts of my codes are welcomed

Comment: How is your tailor model ?

Comment: @Icguida if you're asking about the contents of the **tailor.rb** it os like this:

`class Tailor < ActiveRecord::Base`
 `has_many :products`
`end`

I didn't do any migrations for the tailor model since it's the parent class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `@tailor.Product`. `Product` is the class name and not the association name.

I **strongly** recommend you to read the [`has_many`association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association).

But, assuming you have a `has_many` association between `Tailor` and `Product`, you should be doing something like this:

```
def new
  @tailor = Tailor.find(params[:tailor_id])
  @product = @tailor.products.build
end

def create
  @tailor = Tailor.find(params[:tailor_id])
  @product = @tailor.products.create(params[:product]) # Take a look at strong parameters
  @product.save
end
```

You can read about the associations methods [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)